# Is there an idiom for the maximum amount of surprise?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Looking for an expression of extreme surprise.

I've got shock, amazement, aghast and the rest of the the thesaurus, but I'm really seeking something more idiomatic.

Ideally the phrase/idiom would exude positivity, such as finding a treasure.

Answer (score 2):

You might use:

> [***surprised beyond belief***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=surprised+beyond+belief&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csurprised%20beyond%20belief%3B%2Cc0)

[Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/beyond%20belief) says of *beyond belief*:

> You use *beyond belief* to emphasize that something is true to a very great degree or that it happened to a very great degree.

Here's an example usage from the book [*Secrets from the Operating Room: My Experiences, Observations, and ...*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NjSrBZ_ZvNIC&pg=PA125&dq=%22surprised+beyond+belief%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj70ofA1KDJAhWDpYgKHXPICsUQ6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q=%22surprised%20beyond%20belief%22&f=false):

> I was surprised beyond belief and was excited.

Answer (score 1):

***not believe one's (own) eyes***

> : to think that something you see is not likely to be real *She looked
>   so different in a uniform, I couldn't believe my eyes*. Usage notes:
>   sometimes scarcely or hardly are used instead of not: 
>   *When he found the ring in the grass, he could scarcely believe his eyes*
>   [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+believe+eyes)

***knock/throw for a loop***; ***knock down or over with a feather***; ***knock sideways***.

> Overcome with surprise or astonishment, as in *Jane was knocked sideways when she found out she won*. The
>   first two of these hyperbolic colloquial usages, dating from the first
>   half of the 1900s, allude to the comic-strip image of a person pushed
>   hard enough to roll over in the shape of a loop. The third hyperbolic
>   term, often put as You could have knocked me down with a feather,
>   intimating that something so light as a feather could knock one down,
>   dates from the early 1800s; the fourth was first recorded in 1925. [The
>   American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+for+a+loop).

Answer (score 1):

***[Take someone's breath away](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+breath+away) :***

> - Fig. to overwhelm someone with beauty or grandeur; to surprise or astound someone. *The magnificent painting took my breath away. Ann looked so beautiful that she took.*

The Free Dictionary

Comment: I have got my breath taken away or breathtaking

Answer (score 0):

The first phrase that comes to mind is "shocked delight".
I've also seen "to his amazement and delight".

Answer (score 0):

> [Blown Away](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blow%20away)
>
> - to impress very strongly and usually favorably

*She was blown away by the amount of treasure*

> [Jaw dropped](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaw-dropping)
>
> - causing great surprise or astonishment

*Her jaw dropped at the site of the treasure*